# GameCube's internal clock keeps telling the wrong time

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

I'm afraid that my GameCube may be losing time. It says 11:30 when it's really 11:35, and after a while it will say it's 15:00 (3:00 PM) when it's really 14:15 (2:15 PM). Is there some way I can remedy this?

Comment: I doubt it, since it's a closed system.

Comment: @Tkdestroyer2 That actually depends on what you mean by "closed"; some geeks were able to run Linux on it: http://www.gc-linux.org/wiki/Main_Page Of course, some of the modifications were made by actually modifying the hardware, but this site's documentation has instructions so that you can actually run unofficial stuff without directly modifying the GameCube.

Comment: Of course, that has nothing to do with my time problem, which could be solved, even if it means unconventionally.

Comment: Troubleshooting question:  Is the GCN plugged directly into the wall, or does it get unplugged/disconnected? (using a surge protector or some of those electrical vamp stopping.)  I'm thinking the issue might be due to the internal battery starting to fade (and losing it's ability to keep the clock counting steadily) but that shouldn't be the case if it has uninterruptible access to electricity.

Comment: @NBN-Alex Thanks for that tip. It could be that, since it is plugged into an extension cord, and it gets moved around a lot. I also had no idea it had an internal battery; can that be replaced, in case it goes dead?

Comment: My GameCube was pretty bad at keeping time even when it was new. Also recently North America switched from daylight savings time, so depending on where you live and how long "after a while" is, that may explain most of the 45 minute difference you described.

Comment: @RossRidge It loses much more than 45 minutes. That was just an example. My GameCube had lost an *entire day* before, but thanks to the answer by agent86 below, it may be a battery problem.

Comment: My GameCube has lost entire days as well. Like I said, it was pretty bad a keeping even when new. Also your example has it gaining time not losing it, which is another reason why I brought up DST. Anyways, I don't think the problem is with the battery, as that would cause it to lose its time completely when not plugged in. I think it's just a problem with they way the GameCube is designed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GameCube has an internal battery that appears to keep the clock running even when the system is powered off.  If this battery is weak or dead, the clock is likely to have issues.  It's impossible for me to point the finger and be 100% sure that's your problem, but it's a likely candidate.

The battery is located just behind the controller ports, mounted to the board the ports are on. You'd have to disassemble the outer casing of the GameCube and then remove the daughterboard that contains the controller ports to get access to it.  ([Photo](http://techforums.nintendo.com/thread/26785) or [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpVVABJyZFk))

The battery inside the GameCube is a CR2032 with soldier tabs welded on.  Replacing one of these properly requires desoldering the leads, removing the old battery, and then resoldering the new battery in its place.  Also it would help if you soldered it in using the same orientation as the old one :)

It's not terribly difficult to do this if you've got even beginner soldering skills.  It's a through-hole part, with large leads and good clearance from other areas of the board.  You just have to buy a CR2032 with the solder tabs attached, these go for pretty cheap on Amazon and/or eBay.

If soldering is just not in the cards, you could hack it a bit.  Some folks have had luck breaking the welds against the battery itself, and then using electrical tape to hold a new (tabless) battery against the old solder tabs.  This is not as elegant or permanent a solution, but it could work in a pinch.

Alternatively, try taking the GameCube to a used games shop and explain the issue and see what they'd charge to fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks, agent86. Knowing about the CR2032 battery helps, since I know these can easily be obtained. I'll see if I can replace it.

Comment: Good answer, but I hate the electrical tape idea. Long term, I think it will ruin the board, as the adhesive on electrical tape always comes off as a kind of goo.

Comment: The first link (“Photo”) is broken.